# jcrop after adding setSelect strange error

Tags: behavior, jcrop

the problem is this: when I initializing Jcrop with such parametrs, below, everything works fine but after i add setSelect: [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ], with any parametrs setSelect: [ 0, 0, 430, 300 ], no matter, i have an error in console

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'tellSelect'`

My code is:

```
longFooter.find('#cutImage').click(function(){
    $('#target').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 43 / 30,
        keySupport: false,
        maxSize:[430, 300],
        trueSize: [parseInt(img.attr("native-width")),parseInt(img.attr("native-height"))],
        bgColor: 'black',
        bgOpacity:   .4,
        onSelect: function (){
            var selection = this.tellSelect();
            var src_x = selection.x;
            var src_y = selection.y;
            var dest_w = selection.w;
            var dest_h = selection.h;
            $('#dllImage').removeAttr("onclick");
            $('#dllImage').attr("onclick", "getCropImage("+"''"+","+"'"+cropUrl+"'"+","+"'"+src_x+"'"+","+"'"+src_y+"'"+","+"'"+dest_w+"'"+","+"'"+dest_h+"'"+")");
            console.log(src_x, src_y, dest_w, dest_h);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older, but you might need to change this:

`var selection = this.tellSelect();`

into this:

`var selection = $(this).tellSelect();`